# Dynamically switching to unknown schemas using hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Using hibernate I need to switch dynamically to different schemas in the same database.
By unknown schemas what I mean is that the schema names are determined only in runtime, so they are unknown before. This is because the schema names are read from files that come from outside the application at runtime. This implies I can't use hibernate.cfg to configure it.

I already checked this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-dynamic-table-routin

 But I don't think that's the solution because the string replacement is done before runtime.
Then I read this 
http://web.archive.org/web/20071011173719/http://hibernate.org/429.html 
But I could not find any examples of that ones.

BTW, can anyone help me with this question?
[org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758744/org-springframework-aop-framework-aopconfigexception-cannot-proxy-target-class)